# WatchOS 2 not reading NSData from iPhone AppDelegate

Tags: swift, ios9, appdelegate, watchos-2

I need help or an extra eye to find out why my query and methods aren't returning data to the Apple Watch. I am trying to populate my table with images that have `PFFiles` stored in my parse database. When my messages require a String back, they are going through, but not when I'm requesting NSData back. I am having to ask for an NSData file back because the Watch does not conform to parse protocols, I've learned. So I am trying to convert them on the AppDelegate side, then transfer as NSData.

Here's my AppDelegate:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "dogInfo")
query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)
query.orderByAscending("dogName")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil && objects!.count > 0 {

        var dataArray = [NSData]()

        for object in objects! {

            if let message = object["imageFile"] as? PFFile {

                message.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        dataArray.append(data!)
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        replyHandler(["images":dataArray])
    }
})
```

This is how I'm retrieving it on the Watch InterfaceController side:

```
self.session.sendMessage(["content":"getImages"], replyHandler: { (result) -> Void in

    if let imagesRequest = result as? [String:[NSData]] {

        if let dogData = imagesRequest["images"] {

            self.imageFiles = dogData

            print("Imagefiles count:\(self.imageFiles.count)")                                              
            self.logInLabel.setHidden(true)
            self.loadTableData()
        }
    }

}, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
    print("got images error: \(error)")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are filling up your `dataArray` inside an asynchronous block (`message.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`), and returning it outside of that block, before it has a chance to populate it.

Comment: Yes it seems I am. Do you have a solution that I could try?