# Need help converting contents of array from PFFile to NSData then transferring to app extension

Tags: swift, ios9, appdelegate, watchos-2

I feel like my code is close to transferring an NSData array to my Apple Watch app extension. Since Apple Watch doesn't conform to Parse protocol, I need to convert my PFFiles to NSDatas (or UIImages), then transfer them over. I am either doing it way wrong or i just have a few lines of code in the wrong place. Data is coming from my parse database that I know has data, that I've tested.

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        var fileArray = [PFFile]()
        var imageArray = [NSData]()

        if error == nil && objects!.count > 0 {

            for object in objects! {

                if let message = object["imageFile"] as? PFFile {

                    fileArray.append(message)
                }
            }
        }

        for object in fileArray {
            object.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
                imageArray.append(data!)

            })

        }
        print(fileArray)
        print(imageArray)
        replyHandler(["images":imageArray])
    })
```

print(fileArray) prints the correct PFFiles but print(imageArray) prints "[ ]".

Comment: You're printing the image array before the asynchronous `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` method has appended anything to that array. Seems like [someone already explained that to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072340/watchos-2-not-reading-nsdata-from-iphone-appdelegate).

Answer (score 1):

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

    var fileArray = [PFFile]()
    var imageArray = [NSData]()

    if error == nil && objects!.count > 0 {

        for object in objects! {

            if let message = object["imageFile"] as? PFFile {

                fileArray.append(message)
            }
        }
    }

    for object in fileArray {
        object.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
            imageArray.append(data!)
            print(imageArray)
            replyHandler(["images":imageArray])
        })

    }
    print(fileArray)


})
```

Well, you may feel that the imageArray is printed too often and that the replyHandler is probably called too often.

However, as the block is executed asynchronously well after the current method is finshed, there is no chance to print or process the result from within this method.

Comment: Yes, so I ran this and I am just getting the first item in the imageArray, but it is populating my table so thats good! If there is no chance to print or process the result from this way, should I try a completely different way to transfer my data? Thanks for your help man.

Comment: You do get all of the images in that array, but not on the first call of the block. The block is called each time when request is finished. You should understand asynchronous processing and blocks and then find a smarter way of dealing with the rather large number of tasks that are excecured concurrently here.

Comment: I get what you mean, after debugging I see how and when it gets fired. I just need to find another way.. Thanks a lot! I've voted for your answer but it doesn't show until i get a few more rep points.